# Symmetric cryptography and salt

Tags: encryption, cryptography, salt, encryption-symmetric

I need to encrypt two-way (symmetric) distinct tokens. These tokens are expected to be repeated (e.g. They are people first names), but I do not want an attacker to conclude which encrypted tokens came from the same original tokens. Salt is the way to go for one-way cryptography (hashing).

Is there a method that can work in symmetric cryptography, a workaround or an alternative?

Answer (score 5):

Yes. Properly used, symmetric encryption does not reveal anything about the plaintext, not even the fact that multiple plaintexts are the same.

Proper usage means choosing a mode of operation that uses an initialization vector (IV) or nonce (that is, not ECB), and choosing the IV appropriately (usually random bytes). Encrypting multiple plaintexts with the same key and IV allows this attack pretty much just like with ECB mode, and using a static IV is a common mistake.

Comment: Note that you may need to pad the usernames to a specific size unless are ok with leaking information about the size of the name.

Comment: @ntoskmi Very dense answer. Could you point to a resource that might elaborate further on what is ECB and how the IV is known at decryption time?

Comment: @yannisf Wikipedia has an article about [modes of operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation). Note in particular the set of images depicting a penguin. You can simply send the IV along with the ciphertext; it doesn't need to be kept secret.

Comment: @ntoskrnl See [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned above, properly utilizing a symmetric encryption scheme would NOT reveal information about the plaintext. You mention the need to protect the users against a dictionary attack on the hidden tokens, and a properly utilized encryption scheme such as GCM would provide you with this property.

I recommend utilizing **GCM mode** as it is an efficient authenticated encryption scheme. Performing cryptographic functions on unauthenticated data may lead to security flaws so utilizing an authenticated encryption scheme such as GCM is your best bet. Note that this encryption scheme along with other CPA-SECURE schemes will provide you security against an adversary that wishes to learn the value of an encrypted token.

For example, in correctly implemented GCM mode, the encryption of the same last name will result in a different ciphertext i.e GCM Mode is Non-Deterministic.

Make sure to utilize a secure padding scheme and fix a length for the ciphertexts to make sure an attacker can't use the lenght of the ciphertext to learn some information about the contents of what generated this token.

Be careful however, you can't interchangeably use hash functions and symmetric encryption schemes as they are created for very different purposes. Be careful with how you share the key, and remember that once an adversary has knowledge of the key, there is nothing random about the ciphertext.

-NOTE- 
**Using encryption incorrectly** : If every user is utilizing the same key to encrypt their token then they can simply decrypt everyone else's token and see the name that generated it.
To be safe, every user must encrypt with a different key so now you have to somehow store and manage the key for each user. This may be very painful and you have to be very careful with this.

However if you are utilizing salts and hash functions, then even if every user is utilizing the same salt to compute hash(name||salt), a malicious user would have to brute force all possible names with the salt to figure out what generated these tokens.

So keep this into consideration and be careful as hash functions and symmetric encryptions schemes can't be used interchangeably.

Answer (score -1):

Assuming that the only items to be ciphered are the tokens (that is, they are not embedded in a larger data structure), then Inicialization Vectors (IV's) are the way to go.

They are quite simple to understand: let M be your token, padded to fit the block size used in the symmetric ciphering algorithm (I'm assuming it's AES) and IV be a random array of bits also the size of the ciphering block.

Then compute C = AES_ENCRYPT(M xor IV, K) where C is the ciphered data and K the symmetric key. That way, the same message M will not be ciphered the same way multiple times since IV is randomly obtained every time.

To decrypt M, just compute M = (AES_DECRYPT(C, K) xor IV).

Of course, both IV and K must be known at decryption time. The most usual way to transmit the IV is to just send it along the ciphered text. This does not compromise security, it's pretty much like storing a salt value, since the encryption key will remain unknown for everybody else.

Comment: There is an assumption that the data to be encrypted is less than or equal to the block size, that may not be the case, also there is no help with how to pad the data in such a way that is is secure and can be removed on decryption. The general method is to use CBC mode with PKCS#7 padding options where the IV is a different random value for each encryption and is prefixed to the encrypted data.

Comment: You're right, it might have been a wrong assumption. In such cases, using CBC is indeed highly recommended. To clarify, CBC mode consists in performing the same operations as described in my answer but using the previous ciphered block for the xor operation instead of the inicialization vector.